# Ranking risky routes

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, unsupervised-learning, ranking

i'm looking to get the top 10 rank of the most dangerous routes. I have a routes table where each row is a route and it has features such as

- avg daily traffic for past three years
- No. of times where there was hard acceleration recorded
- No. of times for drivers using cell phone
- No. of times for hard braking.
- No. of accidents

My initial approach was the following:

- Run anomaly detection using either isolation forest/density based clustering techniques.
- Filter for anomalies - i.e potential risky routes
- Apply 2nd layer of clustering i.e. kmeans to identify riskiest road cluster group.

Question for the community:

- Am I on the right track? If so, the issue with my approach is after finding the riskiest cluster group it only informs that these are the riskiest routes. I don't know which is one is more risky.
- Are there any other ways of thinking about this problem?

Appreciate any guidance on this. Thanks

Joe

Comment: Ultimately you need a single numeric score for each route that weights the different features according to how much you think they contribute to whether a road is dangerous or not. I don't see this as a machine learning, unsupervised clustering, or anomaly detection problem at all - what makes a road "risky" is entirely up to you. Machine learning can't tell you if a road with 10 accidents, 5 fatalities and 100 phone users is "more dangerous" than a road with 12 accidents, 4 fatalities and 90 phone users.